# How to use GroupBy in LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

In `listProducts` I have a field called "family". I want to `GroupBy` this field.

```
var products = from listProducts in repository.All() 
               where (listProducts.Code == "48654")
               select listProducts;`
```

Comment: You could google your very own title for immediate answers.

Comment: This is a duplicate, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452161/linq-and-groupby and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887644/linq-how-to-do-groupby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
var products = from listProducts in repository.All()
                where listProducts.Code == "48654"
                group listProducts by listProducts.family into grp
                select grp;
```

For more information visit [LINQ Group By](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/514424/LINQ-Group-By)